# How debug placeholder pseudo element in firefox?

Tags: css, debugging, firefox, firebug

I have CSS code like this:

```
:-moz-placeholder,::-moz-placeholder {
    color:    #999;
    /*some additional font styling*/
}
```

I can click "Inspect element" and see all style information about element. But where I can see all CSS rules that has applied to element placeholder?

Comment: You want to be looking along the lines of **Show User Agent CSS** (for firebug) , though it's different for each browser / DOM inspection tool. I'll write a full answer, if I get the time today.

Comment: It sounds like your using the inbuilt Firefox Inspection Tool. So you want to go _Inspect Element (Q) > Computed > Tick the box 'Browser styles' , at the bottom_

Answer (score 9):

Just to give an updated answer for anyone still coming to this page, in FireFox v66, you can reveal pseudo-element styles simply by clicking on the expand icon in the styles panel when inspecting an element in the Developer Tools- see screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Placeholder is a pseudo-element, like ::before and ::after (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) sometimes refered as pseudo-class (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pseudo-classes)

These types of elements could not be seen in the Firefox Inspector, you needed at least Firebug or Chrome Dev Tools, but recently it's available in the Firefox Inspector, too. They are part of the "shadow dom" (extreme simple description: elements created by the browser inside of other elements).

You should be able to find the placeholder in the dom inspectors inside your input or textarea elements, e.g. select an input element, then choose "inspect element" from right click menu, then you should see something like that:

**Firefox Inspector**

[image: Firefox Inspector Pseudo Elements]

**Chrome Dev Tools**

[image: ChromeDevTools Inspect Element]

For Chrome you may need to enable "Show user agent shadow DOM" in the Dev Tools settings.

Comment: This answer would be even better if you went on to explain where in Firbug and/or Chrome Tools to find the placeholder.

Comment: In Chrome you can switch the shado dom via the cog wheel in the above picture (or close to). That opens the settings and there is a "Show Shadow Dom" option, check that and refresh the page to see the shadow DOM.

Comment: Pseudo-element differs from pseudo-class. As per the spec: "'::' starts a pseudo-element, ':' a pseudo-class" (at http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4 )

Comment: It appears that pseudo-classes are now shown in Firefox's built-in tools via right-clicking the element (and pseudo-elements appear to be shown now in their own section).

Answer (score 3):

1. In your address bar, go to: about:config
2. Search for the property: dom.webcomponents.enabled and mark it as true.
3. If your already on a development page, remember to reload it.

After that you will be able to click on pseudo elements :before & :after and see their style.
Not sure why is this disabled, in Chrome works by default.

From this [link](https://www.designedbyaturtle.co.uk/2015/how-to-enable-web-components-in-firefox-shadow-dom/)

Comment: I don't see that config key in firefox; the only one with webcomponents in the name for me is `dom.webcomponents.shadowdom.report_usage`