# See all css properties including pseudo selectors on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: css, css-selectors, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I would like to see all the css properties and states of an element.

I wonder if it's possible to show on inspector on Firefox or chrome the `:hover` css and other pseudo selectors as `:active`, `:focus`, etc. without ticking it in each element.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How debug placeholder pseudo element in firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673224/how-debug-placeholder-pseudo-element-in-firefox)

Comment: unfortunately no. but the solution to display the hover, active and focus it might be in the about:config page